# How to add usage limit for free version of Google Add On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

There are Google docs add-ons which only let you send certain emails a day or process a certain number of rows per day in the free version. Moving to a paid plan for these add-ons removes these restrictions.

How can such limits be put on the use of add-on? Where is the data on the number of usage is stored?

Comment: I believe you are asking for Quotas for Google Services, if I understood you right. For details, you can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) regarding your concern. "*Quotas are set at different levels for users of consumer accounts (like gmail.com), Google Apps free edition (discontinued), or G Suite.*"

Answer (score 2):

You want to write and read values when users use add-on. And you want to do the values in secret. If my understanding is correct, how about using PropertiesService? From your situation, I thought that the condition that users cannot directly retrieve the value may be important. In order to satisfy this condition, I think that there are 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1

Use [`PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service).

When it writes a value, you can use this.

- `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("key", value)`

When it reads a value, you can use this.

- `var value = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("key")`

Please add these scripts in the project with add-on.

#### Note for pattern 1 :

- The values written at add-on can't be read from the other bound script, the other standalone script and Drive API. The values can be read from only the add-on.

### Pattern 2

Use [Custom File Properties of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties).

When it writes a value, you can use this.

- Endpoint: `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###`
- Request body: `{"appProperties": {"key": value}}`

When it reads a value, you can use this.

- Endpoint: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###?fields=appProperties`

Please add these scripts in the project with add-on.

#### Note for pattern 2 :

- `### file ID ###` is the file ID of active document. This can be retrieved from add-on.
- `appProperties` is the private properties. So the values can be read from only the project which wrote the values. Namely, the values can be read from only the add-on.

### Note :

- By writing and reading the secret values, you can give the limitation using the values.
- In my environment, using above 2 patterns, I couldn't find the methods for reading and writing values from the projects except for the project of add-on. So I thought that this can be used for your situation. But please remember that such methods might be found in the future.

### References :

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [Custom File Properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @ledzee If you have any issues for this, feel free to tell me.